# AngularJs : change state using $state.go but want to redirect state's specific elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two controllers situated at different folder & using UI-router to go to different states.

able do that using $state.go('app.to-do') form "app.dahsboard" state.

I want to go to a specific element of app.to-do state !!!

how do I do it ??  is $state.go have any functionality or is there any other ways is there ??

Please help !!

```
   for example:
    from dashboard controller
         { 
           //on ng-click
            $scope.starechange = funtion () {
                $state.go('app.to-do');
                 //but want to go to specific elements of state 'app.to-do'
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options
and get with $stateParams